# ayuda shared preferences

Tags: android-studio, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences, double

Quiero guardar una localización con `shared preferences` como no puedo guardar objetos guardo solo la latitud y la longitud, la transformo en *string* las guardo y despues las saco y las transformo en *double* de vuelta para cargarlas a las variables de location que tenia pero me salta error y no lo puedo solucionar.

Este es el método para cargar las preferencias el cual lo llamo desde el `oncreate`:

```
public void cargarpreferencias(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("localizaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String latcasastr = preferences.getString("latcasa","a");
    double latitudcasa=Double.parseDouble(latcasastr);

    String longcasastr = preferences.getString("longcasa",null);
    double longitudcasa=Double.parseDouble(longcasastr);

    String lattrabajostr = preferences.getString("lattrabajo",null);
    double latitudrabajo=Double.parseDouble(lattrabajostr);

    String longtrabajostr = preferences.getString("longtrabajo",null);
    double longitudtrabajo=Double.parseDouble(longtrabajostr);

    String latfacultadstr = preferences.getString("latfacultad",null);
    double latitudfacultad=Double.parseDouble(latfacultadstr);

    String longfacultadstr = preferences.getString("longfacultad",null);
    double longitudfacultad=Double.parseDouble(longfacultadstr);

    loccasa.setLatitude(latitudcasa);
    loctrabajo.setLatitude(latitudrabajo);
    locfacultad.setLatitude(latitudfacultad);
    loccasa.setLongitude(longitudcasa);
    loctrabajo.setLongitude(longitudtrabajo);
    locfacultad.setLongitude(longitudfacultad);
}
```

Este es el código que uso para guardar las preferencias que estaria funcionando bien:

```
public void guardarpreferencias() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("localizaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    String latcasastr = String.valueOf(latcasa);
    editor.putString("latcasa",latcasastr);
    String longcasastr = String.valueOf(longcasa);
    editor.putString("longcasa",longcasastr);
    String lattrabajostr = String.valueOf(latrabajo);
    editor.putString("lattrabajo",lattrabajostr);
    String longtrabajostr = String.valueOf(longtrabajo);
    editor.putString("longtrabajo",longtrabajostr);
    String latfacultadstr = String.valueOf(latfacultad);
    editor.putString("latfacultad",latfacultadstr);
    String longfacultadstr = String.valueOf(longfacultad);
    editor.putString("longfacultad",longfacultadstr);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.Location.setLatitude(double)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.houth.ubicaciontp.MainActivity.cargarpreferencias(MainActivity.java:286)
>           at com.example.houth.ubicaciontp.MainActivity$1.onLocationResult(MainActivity.java:61)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente define un valor default de "0" (o el valor numérico que desees como default) para que ese sea convertido sin problema a `Double`, evita usar `null` en este caso:

```
String longcasastr = preferences.getString("longcasa","0");
double longitudcasa=Double.parseDouble(longcasastr);

String lattrabajostr = preferences.getString("lattrabajo","0");
double latitudrabajo=Double.parseDouble(lattrabajostr);

String longtrabajostr = preferences.getString("longtrabajo","0");
double longitudtrabajo=Double.parseDouble(longtrabajostr);

String latfacultadstr = preferences.getString("latfacultad","0");
double latitudfacultad=Double.parseDouble(latfacultadstr);

String longfacultadstr = preferences.getString("longfacultad","0");
double longitudfacultad=Double.parseDouble(longfacultadstr);
```

Segundo, no estas inicializando las variables `loccasa`, `loctrabajo`, `locfacultad`, etc:

```
loccasa.setLatitude(latitudcasa);
loctrabajo.setLatitude(latitudrabajo);
locfacultad.setLatitude(latitudfacultad);
loccasa.setLongitude(longitudcasa);
loctrabajo.setLongitude(longitudtrabajo);
locfacultad.setLongitude(longitudfacultad);
```

por esta razón obtienes el error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.location.Location.setLatitude(double)' on a null object
>   reference

Comment: intente poner " " y "0" pero no funciona de ninguna manera, las variables estan declaradas como generales, esas variables toman valor a la hora de apretar un boton y guarda la localizacion actual de donde estas.

Comment: **las variables están declaradas como generales, pero debe ser inicializadas**, tienen valor de null por eso el problema principal. @Houth

Comment: tenes razon me parecia que era eso, pero no lo intente por que no me sirve esa solucion tampoco, el problema seria que yo tengo 3 botones donde guardo la ubicacion actual para despues contar la distancia en metros, y la idea seria que esas variables se inicializen en un punto cuando apreto el boton no cuando inicio. osea necesitaria que la localizacion este vacia o nula en un principio